# How can I open a door with the knob removed?

Tags: doors

My door automatically locks when you close the door. I of course forgot about it and closed my door as I left now we can't get it open. Please help I'm not sure what to do.

[image]

Comment: If you've removed all the hardware. just stick a blade in there and rotate the locking ring.  But what sort of knobset is *always* locked?   Typically you can  twist a button or ring so it doesn't lock automatically.

Comment: Carl I agree normally a screwdriver will retract the bolt+ although I don’t see the mechanism in the hole or half moon most quickset locks have.

Comment: Yes, you've done 95% of the work.  Now you just need to grab onto the latch in the same way the doorknob does, and pull it to the right.  The methods vary somewhat but the principle is the same.

Comment: As a side note, if you were able to unscrew the door handle from the outside to get to this point, a burglar will be able to do the same. Some might consider this a security issue. ;) If, on the other hand, you destroyed the handle to get to this stage, then you know that's what someone else would have to do to break in.

Comment: looks like you can just grab the plunger on the right side and pull right.

Answer (score 1):

I would just put a screwdriver in the left hole and pull to the right against the spring to withdraw the latch.